# How do I set the encoding for non-Latin characters in zonky Embedded?

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, junit5, embedded-database

I have a **spring-boot** application. I use a **postgres database**. Migration of the database is done **with liquibase**. When executing liquibase changesets I fill some tables, with some characters. For testing, I found a technology such as Zonky Embedded Postgres. And when I test the logic of my application on a real database, the application works correctly.

The problem is that when I run the **tests**, the **zonky test database** gets strange characters through liquibase. It looks like the encoding for non Latin letters is off.

**For example.**
Expected georgian letter: ა;
actually: бѓђ

But everything is **fine with English letters and the coding does not fly off**.

What may be the problem, **please advise**?

My spring-boot-test annotations on the class:

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["classpath:application-test.yml"])
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(
    provider = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseProvider.ZONKY,
    type = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseType.POSTGRES,
    refresh = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.RefreshMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD
)
```

Comment: Well... I just upgraded the liquibase version and it worked. Okay.